# How to monitor popup error in WInForm application

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a very big C# Winform application(contains thousands of exceptions and error popup). Is there any way that I can monitor this application when it popup error? so that I can disappear it and output some signal after catch it.

Comment: What do you mean popup error? the application crashes?

Comment: If you have thousands exceptions means that you probably missing namespaces.

Comment: popup error means exception.

Comment: Hi there and welcome, I suppose the application is full of "try,catch messageBox show" kind of things. Do you have any central popup class that handles this or is full on chaos?

Comment: they are full on chaos,

Answer (score 0):

**Application.ThreadException** (event) that is:

> Occurs when an untrapped thread exception is thrown.
>
> ...
>
> It uses the **ThreadException** event to handle UI thread exceptions, and
>   the **UnhandledException** event to handle non-UI thread exceptions.

Read more about this at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2).

Here is an example code:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            Application.ThreadException += new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);
            Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);

            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }

        static void Application_ThreadException(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Exception.Message, "Unhandled Thread Exception");
        }

        static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show((e.ExceptionObject as Exception).Message, "Unhandled UI Exception");
        }
```

> Caution
>
> Because this is a static event, you must detach your event handlers
>   when your application is disposed, or memory leaks will result.

Comment: Thx so much, it should be a good solution for me. and one more question is how to handle all Form popup? Could you help to give me some suggestion also?

Comment: What popup do you talk about?

Comment: all forms, error messages, during application running

Comment: It will be invoked at all Unhandled exceptions. All.